Need assistance with creating nested IF statements in a AND statement
I have a nested IF statement, in an AND statement. The IF statement ensures that IF an "Approval Date" is entered, a value must be entered in the "Total Budget Amount Approved" column.
My list has multiple columns to input an "approval date" and "total budget amount". I am attempting to replicate this nested IF(ISBLANK criteria a total of 6 times. The cumulative budget amount cannot exceed $1000, hence the AND statement.
So far I have:
=AND([Cumulative TOTAL (not to exceed $1000)]<1001,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE)))

This works great.
However, when I attempt to add more, the validation results in an error. Any thoughts on how to correctly break this down? Below is unsuccessful attempt.
=AND([Cumulative TOTAL (not to exceed $1000)]<1001,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE,,IF(ISBLANK([(2) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(2) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(3) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(3) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(4) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(4) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(5) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(5) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(6) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(6) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE)))

This is an extension of the response received in this post: If one column is not empty, require value in another column
UPDATE (09-20-24)
I tried using a code with the comma and semi colon however, both result in an error. See examples of the two codes below. I included the true names of the columns:
Code 1:
=AND([Cumulative TOTAL (not to exceed $1000)]<1001,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Approval Date  of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Amount of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(2) Approval Date of CNBA],TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(2) Amount  of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(3) Approval Date of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(3) Amount of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(4) Approval Date of CNBA],TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(4) Amount of CNBA],FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(5) Approval Date of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(5) Amount  of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(6) Approval Date of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(6) Amount of CNBA],FALSE,TRUE)))
Code 2
=AND([Cumulative TOTAL (not to exceed $1000)]<1001;IF(ISBLANK([(1) Approval Date  of CNBA]);TRUE;IF(ISBLANK([(1) Amount of CNBA]);FALSE;TRUE));IF(ISBLANK([(2) Approval Date of CNBA];TRUE;IF(ISBLANK([(2) Amount  of CNBA]);FALSE;TRUE));IF(ISBLANK([(3) Approval Date of CNBA]);TRUE;IF(ISBLANK([(3) Amount of CNBA]);FALSE;TRUE));IF(ISBLANK([(4) Approval Date of CNBA];TRUE;IF(ISBLANK([(4) Amount of CNBA];FALSE;TRUE));IF(ISBLANK([(5) Approval Date of CNBA]);TRUE;IF(ISBLANK([(5) Amount  of CNBA]);FALSE;TRUE));IF(ISBLANK([(6) Approval Date of CNBA]);TRUE;IF(ISBLANK([(6) Amount of CNBA];FALSE;TRUE)))

If you want to combine all conditions using AND, you can add those conditions in this format:
=AND(<condition1>,<condition2>,<condition3>)

Example:
=AND([Cumulative TOTAL (not to exceed $1000)]<1001,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(2) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(2) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(3) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(3) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(4) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(4) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(5) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(5) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(6) Approval Date]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(6) Total Budget Amount Approved]),FALSE,TRUE)))

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].
You can add up to 30 conditions inside single AND function.


Update from comments:
You are missing a lot of closing parentheses/brackets in your formula. Try closing all brackets in correct place. Check if below works for you:
=AND([Cumulative TOTAL (not to exceed $1000)]<1001,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Approval Date of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(1) Amount of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(2) Approval Date of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(2) Amount of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(3) Approval Date of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(3) Amount of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(4) Approval Date of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(4) Amount of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(5) Approval Date of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(5) Amount of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)),IF(ISBLANK([(6) Approval Date of CNBA]),TRUE,IF(ISBLANK([(6) Amount of CNBA]),FALSE,TRUE)))


Thank you of working through this with me! I came across an error. Please refer to my "Update 09-20-24" comment, edited into the main post.

check updated answer.

Works as intended, thank you!
